# Spring MVC referencing params variable from RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, request-mapping

I have the method below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path/to/{iconId}", params="size={iconSize}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void webletIconData(@PathVariable String iconId, @PathVariable String iconSize, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    // Implementation here
}
```

I know how to pass the variable "webletId" from the RequestMapping using the @PathVariable, but how do I reference the variable "iconSize" from params?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 41):

Use `@RequestParam`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path/to/{iconId}", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public void webletIconData(@PathVariable String iconId, 
    @RequestParam("size") String iconSize, 
    HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException { ... }
```

**See also:**

- [15.3.2.3 Supported handler method arguments and return types](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments)

Answer (score 18):

[axtavt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000876/spring-mvc-referencing-params-variable-from-requestmapping/5001308#5001308) is right

I only want to explain what your mistake is:

The `@RequestMapping` `params` parameter is a filter to make sure that the annotated handler method is only invoked if there is a parameter with the requested value.

So a handler method annotated with `@RequestMapping(params="action=doSomething")` will be only invoked if there is an request parameter `action`with the content `doSomething`.