# spring pathvariable doesn't work ,can't get the value

Tags: spring, path-variables

when i enter:http://localhost:8080/sys_manager/admin/sys/resource/update/1009
it's can enter into this method,but the id value is null,:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showUpdateForm(@PathVariable("id") ID id, Model model) {
        M m = baseService.findOne(id);
        if (permissionList != null) {
            this.permissionList.assertHasUpdatePermission();
        }
        setCommonData(model);
        model.addAttribute(Constants.OP_NAME, "修改");
        model.addAttribute("m", m);
        return viewName("editForm");
    }
```

One picture more than thousands of words,here is the snapshot:https://plus.google.com/photos/109577783306525329699/albums/6135767537581420673

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000876/spring-mvc-referencing-params-variable-from-requestmapping

Comment: thanks,I  know the api.The problem actually  is that it worked well yesterday, i think i havn't modified nothing about this class and it's relative jsp,

Comment: @vincent Change pathvariable type to String and try again. I think it will work

Answer (score 3):

thanks everyone,I had fixed this problem,it because by override.
the super method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showUpdateForm(@PathVariable("id") ID id, Model model) {
    M m = baseService.findOne(id);
    if (permissionList != null) {
        this.permissionList.assertHasUpdatePermission();
    }
    setCommonData(model);
    model.addAttribute(Constants.OP_NAME, "修改");
    model.addAttribute("m", m);
    return viewName("editForm");
}
```

this subclass's method as blow:

```
@Override
public String showUpdateForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
    return super.showUpdateForm(id, model);
}
```

it will visit child's "showUpdateForm"(even though child'method does't has @RequestMapping).My mistake is that I don't add @PathVariable in child's method .

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to change your controller action like this

```
public String showUpdateForm(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model) {
....
```

If you really want to use use a Custom class object as the `PathVariable`. then you have to registered a custom editor to your controller as below.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(ID.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
        @Override
        public String getAsText() {
            return ((ID) this.getValue()).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            setValue(new ID(text));
        }
    });
}
```

And also note you have to add avariable to store the text value parsed inside that class or inside this initBinder, as per your choice.

Comment: sorry,'ID' here is a generic  Type,actually it's "Long" when running.and i had edit it to Long ,it won't work too.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use the a Spring Data JPA DomainClassConverter, that way you save yourself the findOne lookup, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showUpdateForm(@PathVariable("id") M m, Model model) {
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#_domainclassconverter

Comment: not working i am getting this :Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type []: no matching editors or conversion strategy found